# Create a Unique Field depend on another field value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Need the title field is unique if the privacy field is public 
How to maintain in MySQL database server or any solution

```
id | u_id | title | privacy
--------------------------------
1  |  1   | Hello | public
2  |  2   | Hello | private
3  |  2   | Hello | public      ** is not possible
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of mysql quirks to get what you want.Mysql treats NULL as an unique value in an unique index.So change the privacy column to DEFAULT NULL and add an UNIQUE KEY on `(title,privacy)`.
When you get the data just use NULL as privacy with

```
COALESCE(privacy,'private')
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a548f/1) to play with,try to insert another 'Hello','public' and it will fail

Comment: @Al-Amin This implies you know the right way,so can you elaborate a bit more on why it is wrong?

Comment: i am sorry, Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 tables one for private and one for public privacy records. Then you have to create unique index on title field in "public"tables.

Another way of keeping such a constraint is using triggers before insert and before update that will throw an exception if there is already a record causing a conflict.